# Using Docker YML file with context to parent (..) takes too long to build under WSL2

Tags: docker, nginx, build, docker-compose

I have this folder structure

```
folder_ext
folder_docker
       |---> folder_int
folder_1
folder_2
.......
```

My docker files are all included inside the folder_docker. Inside my docker-compose.yml file, I set the context like this

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    container_name: my_nginx
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: ./folder_docker/nginx/Dockerfile
```

Inside the `Dockerfile` I copy some files from folder_ext

`COPY ./folder_ext /container_folder_ext`

but somewhere below I copy also files from `folder_docker/nginx/nginx.tmp`

`COPY ./folder_docker/nginx/nginx.tmpl /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.tmpl`

I am using also `.dockeringore` to ignore folders & files that I am not using.

Unfortunately, this **takes too long under WSL2 (Ubuntu distro)** to begin the building process about ~45 minutes before it starts to process the 1st command inside the Dockerfile. I don't know why, but that's is a huge problem for me since I want to make many builds and I am losing my time with this stall.

If I use an alternative scenario like this below, where context is set inside the `folder_ext`,

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    container_name: my_nginx
    build:
      context: ../folder_ext
      dockerfile: ../folder_docker/nginx/Dockerfile
```

the build begins almost instantly (~2 seconds) BUT I get an error "**docker forbidden path outside the build context**" for the 2nd COPY

`COPY ../folder_docker/nginx/nginx.tmpl /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.tmpl`

I don't want to move my folder infrastructure just to make it build faster because it's a git project that follows this folder structure. This seems to be a WSL2/Windows problem since under the production server the building times are acceptable.

Any other solution?

Comment: Are some of the `folder_n` very large?  Do you get any output while you're waiting?

Comment: @DavidMaze hi, thank you for your answer. When I include in the .dockeringnore all the parent folders it works just fine. When I exclude only the specific folder ie `folder_ext` that I use also in the 2nd scenario, it gets stalled again. Inside the `folder_ext` I have also a .dockerignore that excludes all the folders I want to ignore. It drives me crazy. On the production server (not local) all scenarios work just fine. Only in my local machine, I have this problem which is a git image like the one I have on the production server.

Comment: @DavidMaze Using --verbose and --log-level DEBUG I get no info. Just "building xxxx"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the `.dockeringore` files inside the subfolders are **IGNORED**.

The original `.dockeringnore` file in the parent was like that.

```
.git
node_modules
build
```

Inside each parent folder like `folder_ext`, `folder_1`, `folder_2` etc have also their own `.dockerignore` files for their subfolders like this

```
node_modules
build
discard
```

It seems that `docker-compose` takes in mind only the 1st `.dockeringone` file that lives in the parent directory according to context.

I fixed the problem with the following. I used only one `.dockeringore` file that exists in the parent folder and deleted all subfolder's `.dockerignore`. Then I changed the exclusions of the one and only parent `.dockeringore` file like this.

```
.git
node_modules
build 
folder_ext/node_modules
folder_ext/build
folder_1/node_modules
folder_1/build
folder_1/discard
folder_2/node_modules
folder_2/build
folder_2/discard
```